# Mysql query how to match column key and value

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.6

I have query with this

```
->leftjoin(
    DB::raw("(
        SELECT transactable_id AS invoice_id, transactions.payment_method_id, payment_methods.name AS payment_method, SUM(transactables.amount) AS trans_amount
        FROM transactions
        join payment_methods on payment_methods.id = transactions.payment_method_id
        join transactables on transactables.transaction_id = transactions.id
        and transactions.deleted_at is null
        and transactables.deleted_at is null
        and transactable_type = 'Sale'
        GROUP BY transactable_id

    ) AS trx"), 'trx.invoice_id', '=', 'sales.id', 'GROUP BY trx.invoice_id')
->addSelect(DB::raw('IFNULL(trans_amount , 0.00 ) AS trans_amount'),DB::raw('trx.payment_method'))
```

Return result from the select like

```
+"trans_amount": "200.00"
+"payment_method": "Cash"
```

How to form the data base on the value like

```
+"Cash": "200.00"
```

Comment: Not simply done, me thinks.  https://vitobotta.com/2015/12/10/mysql-dynamic-column-name/ How might your results vary?  Where is your table schema?

Comment: mysql questions are best accompanied with a db-fiddle demo link.